# SSD partitioning for Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: partitioning, ssd, ubuntu-gnome

Being rather new to Linux, I need the opinion(s) of more experienced users in some matters like choosing a partitioning scheme for my system. My distro of choice is Ubuntu Gnome (only OS installed at the moment) and my system is a laptop (HDD is a 500 GB SSD).
At the moment I have a boot partition (~250 MB) and an extended partition with the rest of the space on the HDD (created during the installation of the OS).
To divide the extended partition, I believe I'd have to unmount it first (which doesn't seem feasible while running the OS from it), so I am thinking to make a bootable USB with GParted and boot from it and partition from there. Does this sound right?

As partitions, I'm thinking to create a swap partition as well (although ubuntu gnome strangely didn't make one when I installed it and it seems to be working fine without it), with the same size as my RAM memory; next a 30-40Gb partition (root/) for the system files and for the rest a partition for the /home folder, with system/application dependent config, data and other files (pictures, movies, music).
Does this seem right to you guys? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you for any opinions/suggestions & merry Christmas everyone! :)
Alin

Comment: Just a tip: 250 MB for the /boot partition will soon leave you with no disk space problems and software update errors, since kernel updates will take up space from this partition. I always recommend to put everything in a single partition, but if you really need a separate boot space consider allocating around 5 GB to it and do regular old kernel purges (always remember to keep your current kernel and the previous one).

Comment: Also the big problem of having separate /home and / partitions is that if you install lots of programs the root will be filled in a short time, and dealing with root repartitioning is a pain in the a**. Merry christmas btw

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Eduardo. The boot partition was made during the installation of the OS. I'm not sure if I should increase its size now. About the root partition, you're right, I can make it larger to avoid this, say 60 GB or so.

Comment: Believe me, you should increase the boot partition size. One kernel will barely fit in 250 MB, after 2 or 3 kernel updates you will run out of space.

Answer (score 0):

To repartition, `gparted` on a USB stick is *the* way to go.  Not only does it repartition, but it also grows/shrinks the filesystem within the partition (i.e. it understands the FS internal structure just like `fsck` would).  And, doing it the other way [live] won't work.

A given kernel version takes up about 33MB per rev [with vmlinuz* and initramfs*], so your /boot should be okay.

40 MB for the root partition is also good.  I've got a 60 GB partition for that, and I have a fair number of programs installed, but I'm only using 33 GB.

There's some controversy about what is adequate swap.  Some say just a few GB, regardless of RAM size, but the "old school" [and mine] metric was 2X the RAM size because of the way older Unix kernels had to handle swapin/swapout.  I'd say *minimally* at least the RAM size.  Depends on how much RAM you have.  With 4 GB of RAM, I'd *definitely* add swap.  With 24 GB of RAM, you may be able to skip the swap altogether.

I have large raid HDs, and I occasionally run the odd batch number cruncher program that will use way more memory than I have RAM, so I have about 120 GB.  That may be the deciding factor on how large to go (e.g. accomodating whatever "memory hog" programs you intend to run)

However, one thing [for you] to consider is the fact that you've got an SSD.  If it's flash, putting a swap partition on it may strain the flash's wear leveling, etc.  Flash has gotten better about this, so the answer may depend on the specs of your particular SSD.  Normal FS access is usually "write once", "read many", so it doesn't "pound on" the device nearly as much.

With SSDs made from alternatives to flash, such as Intel's "3D XPoint" technology [probably not yet available--but soon], they don't have the wear leveling problem.

Also, when you've got the system fully configured, consider editing `/etc/fstab` and changing the mount options from [probably] `relatime` to `noatime`.  See the `mount` man page for details.  This change reduces writing to the disk when reading.  Every time you read a file, the OS updates the "last accessed time" [or "atime"] in the file's inode, causing a metadata write of this.  The `noatime` prevents this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Craig! I have 16 GB of RAM on my system and I don't have any software that's a massive resource hog in mind that I need to run (at least not yet). That's why I'm considering a 16 GB swap partition.  The SSD that I have is a Samsung 850 EVO M.2 500GB (http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-N5E500BW). It does have 3D V-NAND flash memory architecture, but I'm not sure if it's similar to the 3D XPoint from Intel.

Merry Christmas! :)